# Difference between ListView and AbsListView

Tags: android, api, android-listview

In my project I was using `AbsListView` to handle/create my `ListView` in a `Fragment`. It worked fine, but the Android Studio inspection tells me that `AbsListView` requires API 11. Now I was wondering if it would be better to replace it with `ListView` or if it is enough just casting into `(ListView)` where the `Adapter` is set.

```
private ListView mListView;
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

VS

```
private AbsListView mListView;
((ListView) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: I would just use `ListView`, using the abstract class for type is odd IMHO

Answer (score 0):

If you handle instance as common class type(AbsListView), use the former.
Otherwise, use the latter.

For your information, It's not `API11` that Use of `AbsListView` requires.(`setAdapter` of `AbsListView` requires `API11`).

so, i recommend the use of `ListView`
(`setAdapter` of `ListView` requires `API1`) too

Comment: you havent mentioned the Difference between these!!!

Answer (score 0):

AbsListView is an Abstract Class:

```
 public abstract class AbsListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> implements TextWatcher, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener, Filter.FilterListener, ViewTreeObserver.OnTouchModeChangeListener
```

but ListView is a concrete class (it can be instantiated):

```
public class ListView extends AbsListView
```

from Android Documentation:

**AbsListView** that can be used to implement *virtualized lists* of items.

A list *doesnot have a spatial definition* here.

subclasses of this class can display the content of the list in:

- grid
- carousel
- ListView
- ...

But:

**ListView** Displays a vertically-scrollable collection of views.

each view is positioned immediatelybelow the previous view in the list.

so its fine to Define your List as an AbsListView and Dynamically choose how to implement **The View** as a ListView,GridView, ....

```
private AbsListView mListView;
```

but when you want to **setAdapter**. you have to initialize it as an Instantiate View such as ListView:

```
mListView = new ListView();
```

or:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```